# accessing ubuntu teminal sessions

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to access a terminal session after closing terminal?  I ran into some interesting information about my installation of Ubuntu using the terminal, and I would like to retrieve that material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not if you haven't done something to preserve the session beforehand, like using [`screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/screen.1) to keep the shell alive, or used [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/script.1) to save the output. You could, of course, browse your command history to see which commands you had used:

```
history | less
```